# Recognize emojis given in brackets in a String

Tags: python, string, emoji

I have stored Skype message as Strings (on an Android phone). The Strings can contain Skype emojis. For example a string could be "This is a test (laugh)". The emojis are encoded in brackets, such as (laugh), (smile) and so on.

Now, I would like to count the amount of emojis in a sentence and remove the emojis from the sentence. Of course I could just count the number of () pairs and remove them but this would also remove normal text given in brackets. Moreover, in rare cases it can happen that emojis are also given as :( or :/ and so on.

Is there an elegant way to count the number of emojis in a String and remove them in Python?

Comment: There might be a workflow using the [emoji module](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/).  If you can come up with a test to see if a conversion was made, then I can envisage the following methodology: 1. try to convert the current text (to catch `;-*` etc.); 2. test replacing `(text)` with `:text:` where there are no spaces or parentheses in `text`, and check if such a conversion succeeds

Comment: Looks like it might even work with `emojize(string, delimiters=('(', ')'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Skype and several another programs use its "emoji" format. The true emoji format is strictly specified. There is a Python library for working with true emojis: [emoji](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji). You can try to find your emojis with `delimiters` parameter of `emojize` function and with `emoji_lis` function:

```
import emoji

waka = ':smile: :) (smile) :smiling_face: WAKA (sign_of_the_horns_medium-light_skin_tone) :speak-no-evil_monkey:'
print(emoji.emoji_lis(emoji.emojize(waka, use_aliases=True)))

[{'location': 0, 'emoji': ''}, {'location': 13, 'emoji': '☺'}, {'location': 63, 'emoji': ''}]
```

```
print(emoji.emoji_lis(emoji.emojize(waka, delimiters=('(', ')'))))

[{'location': 39, 'emoji': ''}]
```

Note that you will not find smilings (like `:)`, `:(` etc), only emojis. You can also not find every "emoji" in text because you can't guarantee that Skype is using official emoji names (moreover, I am sure it is **not** using them). If you want to find smilings too, you should construct your own dict with smilings, Skype "emojis" etc.

Comment: How can I count the number of emojis and how can I remove detected emojis from the string with your above approach?

Comment: Do I have to use use_alises=True in emoji.emojize(waka, delimiters=('(', ')'), use_alisases=True)?

Comment: It is not necessary, but you can use it. It will make results better.